# Scale logo on scroll with jQuery, dependant on scroll percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scale down logo in the header as user scrolling down the page.
When he hits a certain breakpoint, scaling should stop. 
Also, scale can't be more or less specified hardcoded sizes.

Live case:
The header is separated into two section - top and bottom. The bottom part is sticky (pos: fixed) and the top part gets faded out (pos: absolute).
Logo should be smoothly scaled, so it's big (140px height) when all header elements are visible and small (50px height) when it's sticky

So, I can't figure out how to calculate a number within a range of `limit[0]` and `limit[1]` that is dependant on the percentage of scroll distance between 0 and 100 (100 is a header top height in my case)

Currently, it's scaling 1 to 0, but I need to scale 1 to 0.357

===

**Short video** (10s) to demonstrate a problem

https://monosnap.com/file/p5P7GMkn3BKKMu9glrnmBiO5X6951z

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/dpmango/pen/EOXVww

===

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) { 
  var vScroll = _window.scrollTop();
  var $logo = $('[js-header-logo]');
  var $top = $('[js-header-top]');
  var topHeight = $top.outerHeight();
  var logoLimits = [1, 0.357] // [140, 50] // scale factor

  var scrollPercent = 1 - (vScroll / topHeight) // 1 -> 0
  var calcedScale = scrollPercent // what is logic ?

  // limit rules
  if ( vScroll > topHeight ){
    calcedScale = logoLimits[1]
  }
  if ( vScroll < 0 ){
    calcedScale = logoLimits[0]
  }

  // set values to DOM
  $logo.css({
    "transform": 'scale('+ calcedScale +')'
  })

});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: @MinderMondo Thank you for the comment, but html is not a case here. It's a javascript question

Comment: @SergeyKhmelevskoy HTML would help us test our solutions to ensure that they meet requirements.

Comment: @Jhecht Thats a good point :) I have added a codepen to question

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is just a simple Linear Normalization formula. I'd written an answer a while back with a basic JS function that takes input bounds (`0` and `100` in your case), the normalized bounds (`0.357` and `1` in your case), and the number you'd like to convert (the current percent), to give you the new number. You can see that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519217/2026606).

Comment: And for some follow-up, I'd actually re-used that same formula in a [much more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53178973/2026606) where someone was trying to convert a test grade (0-100) to a GPA (1.0 - 4.0), if that implementation is more suitable to your specific example.

Comment: @TylerRoper Exactly what I was looking for, but unable to describe. I've added `normalize(vScroll, topHeight, 0, logoLimits[1], logoLimits[0])` from your GPA example and it works! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to have helped :)